# 'Function' Object is not iterable in python while tokenising the data for NLP

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, lstm

I am trying to tokenize the data for a NLP (LSTM). My dataframe has just 4 columns. But i want to create a tokenization only on `'Vendor Names'` columns of my data frame. The code i am using is as follows

```
        def clean_doc(df7):

            df7=df7.replace('--','')
            tokens=lambda x: len (x[df7].split())
            table = str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation)
            tokens = [w.translate(table) for w in tokens]
            tokens = [word for word in tokens if word.isalpha()]
            tokens = [word.lower() for word in tokens]

         return tokens
```

i am getting a error in the following code

```
tokens = [w.translate(table) for w in tokens]
```

the error i am getting is

```
tokens= clean_doc(df7)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-42-b042d195ebb8>", line 1, in <module>
    tokens= clean_doc(df7)
  File "<ipython-input-41-e1f6df2ac78d>", line 8, in clean_doc
    tokens = [w.translate(table) for w in tokens]
TypeError: 'function' object is not iterable
```

Need help on finding how to correct the same

Comment: You are trying to iterate over `tokens`, which is a (lambda) function, hence the error. Why are you defining `tokens` as a lambda?

Comment: if i dont i get the following error '
  File "<ipython-input-36-b042d195ebb8>", line 1, in <module>
    tokens= clean_doc(df7)

  File "<ipython-input-35-20a1f8dc0d7a>", line 5, in clean_doc
    tokens=df7.split()

  File "C:\Users\narakris\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 5067, in __getattr__
    return object.__getattribute__(self, name)

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'split''